# Authentication for Azure Active Directory using adal for node.js application

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, adal.js

I am trying to authenticate users through Azure Active Directory in a node.js application. I am using azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs. Here is the sample code I have replicated https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/username-password-sample.js . I have created a self signed certificate and uploaded to Azure AD using Azure AD power shell. I am still getting certificate un-trsuted error. Can anyone suggest a solution for the issue?

Comment: Could you paste your nodejs code or error information?

Comment: Code is exactly the same as here https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/username-password-sample.js . I am getting 'Cert_Untrusted' error @ context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword() method

Comment: I think you should refer to the "certificate-credentials-sample" code https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/certificate-credentials-sample.js when using self signed certificate.

Comment: I need to use 'UserName-Passowrd' to authenticate.

Comment: OK. It seems to be not related to self signed certificate. The easy way to authenticate users for sign-in nodejs app is using "passport-azure-ad" package, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web/. And there is a sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect for this scene.

Comment: Yes, I tried using passport-azure-ad, but it does not redirect to the azure ad login page like it is supposed to.

Comment: I suggest to refer to passport offical doc and check your code. Could you paste the key code?

Answer (score 1):

The sample code (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/username-password-sample.js) don't need to use any self signed certificate to authenticate user.

Generally, Using management certificate to authentificate for Service Management on Azure, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx.

The easy way to authenticate users for sign-in nodejs app is using "passport-azure-ad" package, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web/. And there is a sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect for this scenario.

The `passport-azure-ad` is a strategy of `passportjs` for Azure AD OpenID connect.

If you just want to authenticate users for using AAD to sign-in apps, you can also try to use `passport-azure-ad-oauth2` https://github.com/auth0/passport-azure-ad-oauth2.

About the usage of `PassportJS`, please refer to http://passportjs.org/docs.